# Unable to Read Excel with huge data

Tags: java

I'm trying to read a Excel with more than 30,000 rows and 50 columns , but the problem that i'm facing is i'm getting "Out of Memory' or 'GC overlimit exceeded issue.

Can any body helkp me out with this problem

Comment: Do you use Apache POI? Show some of your code, otherwise it is hard to help

Comment: If you're using Apache POI, then you're out of luck. You have to increase the memory used by your Java application or manually parse the Excel file as XML and get the desired data.

Answer (score 0):

you may need to increase java-heap size :

```
java -Xmx2048M ExcelReader
```

Comment: Using Apache POI, I needed to read this huge file of 50k rows and lot of formulas and more stuff, and I needed almost 3 GBs of RAM just to load that file =\

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza did POI load all content at once?

Comment: and is there any way to avoid this?

Comment: There is one way that uses less memory but instead creates lot of temporary files and can easily fill your hard disk in a matter of seconds.